# How to get String array in seperate index without spliting

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, string, collections

I am sending array from JS to Java as 
commentarr = ["one,two", "three"];

But in Java List`<String>` it is taking as ["one", "two", "three"] where 2 index from JS is seperated into 3 index in Java.

How to get the values in Java without splitting the "commentarr"

Comment: HINT: commas are the separator for `javascript` arrays.

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you mean by "it is taking as", or how you're sending or receiving the data.

Comment: I think all you have is a typo, where `"one,two"` should be `"one","two"`.

Comment: please provide more explanation about your issue. it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

What you have it's CSV record with coma as delimiter and double quote as quote character. So to parse this you'll need to use some CSV parser. There are several good CSV parsers. For example this code does what you want:

```
import java.lang.String;
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser;
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParserSettings;

public class StamMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "\"value1,value2\",value3";
        System.out.println(str);
        CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
            settings.getFormat().setQuote('"');
        CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
        String[] fields = parser.parseLine(str);
        for (String f : fields)
            System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

Of cause you can use [Apache Commons CSV parser](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html), [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net) or any other CSV parser instead.